# Reading random access files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, wofstream, wifstream

I have developed a C++ application for reading and writing data on a random access file.
(I use Visual C++ 2010)

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
class A
{
public :
    int a;
    string b;
    A(int num , string text)
    {
        a = num;
        b = text;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A myA(1,"Hello");
    A myA2(2,"test");

    cout << "Num: " << myA.a<<endl<<"Text: "<<myA.b<<endl;

    wofstream output; //I used wfstream , becuase I need to wite a unicode file
    output.open("12542.dat" , ios::binary );
    if(! output.fail())
    {
        output.write( (wchar_t *) &myA , sizeof(myA));
        cout << "writing done\n";
            output.close();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "writing failed\n";
    }


    wifstream input;
    input.open("12542.dat" , ios::binary );
    if(! input.fail())
    {
    input.read( (wchar_t *) &myA2 , sizeof(myA2));
    cout << "Num2: " << myA2.a<<endl<<"Text2: "<<myA2.b<<endl;
    cout << "reading done\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "reading failed\n";
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

And output is:

```
Num: 1
Text: Hello
writing done
Num2: 1
Text2: test
reading done
```

But i expect  `Text2: Hello` .
What is the problem??

By the way , How can I do `output.write` inside of my class ( in a function) ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't read and write non-POD structs to and from byte streams like that. Your `A` contains a `std::string` which is not POD, therefore `A` is not POD. Also, the read probably fails.

Comment: I have forget to write my preprosecor commands here ... , question edited.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie , What can I do to write string in file?

Comment: @Arashdn Define a binary format, and write it.  Or use an existing binary format, like XDR.

Answer (score 1):

A is not POD, you can not brutally cast non-POD object to `char*` then write to stream.
You need to serialize `A`, for example:

```
class A
{
public :
    int a;
    wstring b;
    A(int num , wstring text)
    {
        a = num;
        b = text;
    }
};

std::wofstream& operator<<(std::wofstream& os, const A& a)
{
  os << a.a << " " << a.b;
  return os;
}

int main()
{
    A myA(1, L"Hello");
    A myA2(2, L"test");

    std::wcout << L"Num: " << myA.a<<endl<<L"Text: "<<myA.b<<endl;

    wofstream output; //I used wfstream , becuase I need to wite a unicode file
    output.open(L"c:\\temp\\12542.dat" , ios::binary );
    if(! output.fail())
    {
      output << myA;
      wcout << L"writing done\n";
      output.close();
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << "writing failed\n";
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

This sample serializes object myA to file, you can think about how to read it out.

Comment: Even most PODs are problematic.  You generally have to define a format, and write that.  (There's a reason why `istream::read` and `ostream::write` take a `char*`, and not a `void*`.)

Comment: Thanks for reply - But I couldn't understand how you included writing function inside of class ...

Comment: @Arashdn which one don't you understand?

Comment: @billz Second one , I have removed unicode and I am using ofstream and char * as data type , I also removed string and now I have only 2 int values. what is the easiest way to move my writing function inside of class???

Comment: you only need to replace `wofstream` to `ofstream`, `wstring` to `string` then my sample code should work.

Comment: @billz, am a beginner ,  I couldn't understand how can I write object data on a file inside of object ....