# Program that reads and writes integers to a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, integer, fstream

Hello and thank you in advance. This is a very simple question but one that is getting on my nerves. What I want is just to ask for an integer to write to a file and then display every integer. I've learned how to either write to or display from a file and I've been successful at it but when I try to do both at a time it just asks me for the integer and don't display the numbers.
I think it may be a problem related to fstream or to the position of the pointer.

Here is the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::fstream;
using std::endl;

int a;
int x;

int main() {
    fstream in;

    in.open("op.txt", std::ios::app);

    cout << "Write an integer" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    in << " " << x;

    while (in >> a) {
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << in.tellg();
    }

    in.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why do you try to write and read at the same time?
The way you are doing read and write is sequential, so your guess is correct - it is related to file pointer. You need to do some "random access" to the file, in order to read what you have just written to the file.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393774/reading-random-access-files

Comment: So could I also write first ofstream and ask for the number, then close the file, and open it again with ifstream in order to display the integers? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are need to be fixed:

```
in.open("op.txt",std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338775/what-is-iosiniosout) is why you need to do `std::ios::in and out`

the second problem is when you are switching between writing and reading from the file like you stated the problem is with the position of the read pointer

```
in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);//before the while loop;
```

this sets the read position to 0 so the program can read from the file from the beginning.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305480/why-cant-i-read-and-append-with-stdfstream-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Okay, it finally works, thank you VERY much. I thought that std::ios::in and ::out were already into "fstream", now it works. Thanks.